# C - How to create calculator by directly inputting a string of numbers and characters(signs)?

Tags: c, string, calculator

INPUT 1+2-3+4
OUTPUT = 4

INPUT 1+2+3+4
OUTPUT = 10

INPUT -1-2-3-4
OUTPUT = -10

Here's my attempt but i gives wrong result

Code fragment:

```
for(i=0;i<strlen(res)+1;i++){
    if(res[i]=='-'||res[i]=='+'||res[i]=='\0'){
        num[z]='\0';
        dig=atoi(num);
        if(x==0){
            sum=dig;
            x++;
        }
        else{
            if(res[i]=='+')
                sum=sum+dig;
            else if(res[i]=='-')
                sum=sum-dig;
        }
        z=0;

    }
    else{
        num[z]=res[i];
        z++;
}
return sum;
```

Comment: This is a job for [the Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

I'd add print statements to the code to see where it's going wrong. But offhand it looks like when you get to the terminating null (`res[i]=='\0'`) you don't add the final number to `sum`.

I'm making assumptions about the declarations and initializers of num, x and z and that the missing `}` is where the indentation implies.

Answer (score 0):

This line references the array "num", but not the correct index:

```
    dig=atoi(num);
```

It should be fixed if you changed it to:

```
    dig=atoi(num[z-1]);
```

Your solution however doesn't work for calculations with numbers more than one digit long.

Answer (score 0):

> But offhand it looks like when you get to the terminating null (`res[i]=='\0'`) you don't add the final number to `sum`.

That's true, but not the only error; if a `+` or `-` is encountered, the corresponding addition or subtraction is done with the previous instead of the next number. So the input `1+2-3+4` actually computes `1-2+3`, which gives `2`.
You can code your whole loop much simpler using [`strtol`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html):

```
    char *beg, *end = res;
    for (sum = 0; dig = strtol(beg = end, &end, 0), end-beg; ) sum += dig;
```